# Apagar arquivo em uso Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delete

Alguém sabe se é possível excluir um arquivo em `Delphi`, usando a função `DeleteFile`, quando o arquivo estiver aberto?

Desde já obrigado.

Comment: O processo que fica travado o ".eml" o nome do .exe em execução é diferente da sua aplicação, se sim, poderia chamar o comando do CMD `taskkill /f /im ProcessoEml.exe` e então encerraria o processo e então poderia criar o arquivo novamente.. o que acha ?

Answer (score -1):

Não tem como, você precisaria fazer via código fonte no evento `onDestroy` do `Form` para ele alterar o nome, assumir o novo arquivo alterado e excluir o antigo, isso para executável. Para arquivos de texto ele consegue excluir o arquivo mesmo com ele aberto, se tentar salvar ele salva no mesmo lugar que foi excluído.

Comment: Boa tarde JRudolf.

Estou tentando excluir um arquivo ".eml", que está aberto. Tenho uma rotina onde grava este arquivo e já o abre. Se o usuário não o fechar e clicar em gerar novamente o email, ao salva-lo recebo a mensagem que o mesmo já existe e se tento excluir não exclui e continua la.
Desde já obrigado.

Comment: Você poderia fazer uma rotina para forçar a encerrar o processo, se o usuário gerar novamente o arquivo com ele aberto, pode verificar se ele está aberto e dar uma menssagem.